# How to pass custom arguments along with standard arguments in a Documentum job method

Tags: documentum

I configured a job correctly by passing the custom arguments successfully.
Now I want to use the custom as well as standard arguments. But the issue is either standard arguments(job id, user name, docbase name and trace level) are getting passed or the custom arguments only. I am unable to get both types of arguments together.

Could anyone suggest any ways to get that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do the same using the custom argument using the Job artifcats and then checking the checkbox "pass standard argument" in DA. But still I was unable to get the custom and standard arguments together.

For resolving this, I first retrieved the job ID from the standard arguments and then fetched the custom arguments using the following code:

```
IDfId idfJobId = new DfId(stringJobId);
IDfSysObject jobObject = (IDfSysObject) session.getObject(idfJobId);
CustArgument1 = jobObject.getRepeatingString(ATTR_METHOD_ARGS, 0);
```

if there are multiple arguments we can get it using a for loop by incrementing index i

```
CustArgument1 = jobObject.getRepeatingString(ATTR_METHOD_ARGS, i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Send standard arguments as custom arguments, i.e. just add it with your custom arguments. Did this before and it work.

Comment: yes I tried it. But the problem is my Job is to be deployed in multiple docbases. If I send standard arguments are custom then I will have to edit all these arguments again for each doc base.

Comment: I bet you could parametrize arguments within deployment procedure, try and get back with the outcome.

Comment: Sorry I am a little new to that.. can you elaborate a little, how can I do that?

Comment: how did you think to deploy it to multiple docbases? :) it depends on deployment procedure. I think you'll do it via Composer. Anyway look into the deployment procedure, you'll see the options when you gain look&feel.

Answer (score 1):

In the job properties editor in Documentum Composer select the "Standard Arguments" radio button!

Even if you are using custom attributes, the "Standard Arguments" radio button has to be selected.